# What should I check to make sure my camera is okay after sending it in for service?

Tags: repair, maintenance

My Canon EOS-1500d has undergone sensor cleaning at canon's service center.

As a beginner how to inspect if everything is as it was earlier? 
What are the basic things to check(for a complete peace of mind) after your camera has gone for repair or it has been in someone else's hand for some days/time?

Comment: Just use the camera... Unless you want to open it yourself and check every screw, but after that you cannot come back to the shop and complain.

Comment: @xenoid you know I said the "basic" things to check. My understanding is that opening the camera doesn't come under basic checking. Anyways thank you

Answer (score 3):

As a beginner, you should assume that the professional shop you sent the camera to did their job. Verify that whatever problem you sent it in for is fixed, and then carry on shooting as normal. Because people are more likely to complain about problems then report "everything is fine" on the internet, you may have gotten the impression that repair jobs usually come back botched. This is not the case. In fact, usually everything is perfectly fine — and likely *better than new* because the camera from the original factory probably did not get individual attention.

Answer (score 3):

If it’s specifically undergone sensor cleaning, then test this by photographing a white wall at f/22. Look for dust. Is it better than before you sent it in? If yes, carry on. If no, contact your repair shop for a redo.